# Search input via url

Tags: php, html, url, input

I've seen that you can pass inputs into the url, for example:

```
http://mydomain/search/everythingiwanthere/
```

and instead of a 404 page, you get a search page with everythingiwanthere as search input. This is a real example: http://www.gearbest.com/everythingiwanthere-_gear/
, you can put any word instead of everythingiwanthere and the site will search for that word.

I know I can use $_GET and a php script to do that

```
http://mydomain/search/?s=everythingiwanthere
```

but I want to use the method above. I don't know how it's called, neither how it's done. Can you please explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: once you have read the dupe and done your own research, if you have a new question, having tried some code, feel free to again again

Answer (score 0):

Look up `mod_rewrite` on Google. [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708) should help you on the way.